# Insertion sort using tail recursion & first order function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tail-recursion, insertion-sort

I'd like to design an algorithm in Haskell using **tail recursion** and **first order programming** for *insertion sort*

I've came up with this solution

```
isort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
isort [] = []
isort [x] = [x]
isort ( x:xs ) = insert ( isort xs )
    where insert [] = [x]
          insert ( y:ys )
            | x < y = x : y : ys
            | otherwise = y : insert ys
```

But I'm not sure if it uses first order and tail recursion.

Can someone come up with an alternative solution using

- tail recursion
- first order programming

Thanks,

Comment: This doesn't use tail recursion. The `otherwise` clause of `insert` is `y : insert ys` (more clearly written as `(:) y (insert ys)`) the call to `insert` appears as an argument to `(:)`, not in tail position

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "First order programming"? Is that just anything that doesn't take a function as an argument.

Comment: @Lazersmoke yes, exactly.

Comment: I don't think you have any functions as arguments, so isn't it already using "first order programming"?

Comment: @Lazersmoke doesn't this chunk of code `insert ( isort xs )` uses `isort` as an argument?

Comment: No, it uses `isort xs :: [a]` (where a is a rigid tyvar bound by the enclosing `isort`)

Comment: A good approach to making recursive functions tail-recursive is to build the return value as an extra, accumulating parameter.  Here, that might be the initial segment of the list preceding the inserted value.  The final step would then have as its three parameters the start of the list, the value to insert, and the rest of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple version, not using tail recursion nor HOF

```
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort   []   = []
sort  [x]   = [x]
sort (x:xs) = insert x (sort xs)

insert :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
insert x [] = [x]
insert x (y:ys) | x < y     = x:y:ys
                | otherwise = y:insert x ys
```

You can add an  accumulator, that allows us to rewrite the sort using tail recursion:

```
sort' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort' xs = sortAcc xs []

sortAcc :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
sortAcc   []   acc = acc
sortAcc (x:xs) acc = sortAcc xs (insert x acc)
```

`insert` is pretty nicely defined the way it is; but just for the purpose
of using higher order functions, we can define it like:

```
insert' :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
insert' x xs = menores ++ x:mayores
  where (menores,mayores) = span (<x) xs
```

where the section `(<x)` is a function of type `Ord a => a -> Bool` passed to `span`.